# How to return text from visible cells?

Tags: excel, aggregate-functions, subtotal

I want to create a cell that returns the text from visible cells, to link this cell to a chart title. Functions lijke AGGREGATE and SUBTOTAL returns only numbers from visible cells. Is there a way to return text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am likewise unclear what is needed.  However, I created this public function to do something like what you requested:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConcatVisibleWithSeparator(rngRange As Range, strSeparator As String) As String
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strReturn As String
    For Each rngCell In rngRange
        If rngCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            strReturn = strReturn & rngCell.Value & strSeparator
        End If
    Next rngCell
    ConcatVisibleWithSeparator = Left(strReturn, Len(strReturn) - Len(strSeparator))
End Function
```

It is called with an entry in a cell like this:

```
=ConcatVisibleWithSeparator(B2:B7," ")
```

What it does is concatenate everything in the specified range with the specified separator in between values.

Two examples are attached as visuals.

Here:[image: Before Rows are Hidden]

and here:[image: After Rows are Hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Without any type of example, I can only offer the use of the & ...

See:

```
="This is "&C15
```

where cell C15 contains the text "a test"

Or if B15 contains "This is "
then:

```
=B15&C15
```